# search is not working,listing is working in searchchoice package in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

IntrinsicHeight(
child: Container(
width: 85.w,
// height: 5.7.h,
padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.w),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
border: Border.all(
color: Color(0xFFAAB1B6), // AAB1B6 color
),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.sp)
),
child: SearchChoices.single(

```
                    items: departments.map((category) => DropdownMenuItem(

                      value: category,
                      child: Text(category.name),
                    )).toList(),

                    value: _selectedDepartment,
                    searchHint: "Select Department",
                    hint: Text( _selectedDepartment.toString()=='null'?"Select Department" :_selectedDepartment.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 12.sp,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        color: Color(0XFF747E86),
                      ),
                    ),
                    
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedDepartment = value;
                        _selectedDepartment?.id = value?.id;
                      });
                    },

                    isExpanded: true,
                    

                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12.sp,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: Color(0XFF747E86),
                    ),




                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on how is it not working?

Comment: search_choices: is an package to list the data with a search box but im getting list of data showing in dialog box but when i search in dialogue box its not working

Comment: Do you get errors?

Comment: no errors,just searching not working